# Al clickar el botón no se ejecuta la acción en Python y PYQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Hace poco que empecé en esto de Python y ahora estoy haciendo un programa en PYQt5.

En principio este programa consta de una ventana principal, con un label con un texto y varios botones que llaman a diferentes módulos.

De momento el único de estos módulos que tengo en desarrollo es el primero, el de mostrar un personaje aleatorio.

Al pulsar este botón me abre la ventana la cual a su vez incluye un label, y dos botones.

Al pulsar el primer botón quiero que en el label se muestre el resultado y al pulsar el segundo se cierre la ventana y me deje en la ventana principal, pero al pulsar cualquiera de los botones no consigo que haga nada y no consigo ver donde está el error.

Como nota decir los personajes aleatorios estan definidos en varios archivos txt en el directorio listas. Los cuales de momento sólo contienen números para hacer las pruebas, ya que más adelante quiero crear otro módulo donde introducir los datos y otro para listarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El total del programa consta de 4 archivos. Dos que se encargan de la parte gráfica y los otros dos de la funciona

Main_ui.py

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from rnd_char_ui import Ui_Rndchr

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(883, 506)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 10, 401, 111))
        self.label1.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        self.Btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 191, 121))
        self.Btn1.setObjectName("Btn1")
        self.Btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 220, 191, 121))
        self.Btn2.setObjectName("Btn2")
        self.Btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 130, 191, 121))
        self.Btn3.setObjectName("Btn3")
        self.Btn4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 300, 191, 121))
        self.Btn4.setObjectName("Btn4")
        self.Btn5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 300, 191, 121))
        self.Btn5.setObjectName("Btn5")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 883, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuArchivo = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuArchivo.setObjectName("menuArchivo")
        self.menuEditar = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEditar.setObjectName("menuEditar")
        self.menuHerramientas = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHerramientas.setObjectName("menuHerramientas")
        self.menuAyuda = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAyuda.setObjectName("menuAyuda")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuArchivo.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEditar.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHerramientas.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAyuda.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:18pt; font-weight:600;\">SCRIPT RANDOMIZER</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.Btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Personaje Aleatorio"))
        self.Btn2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Porcentual Aleatorio"))
        self.Btn3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Entero Aleatorio"))
        self.Btn4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Añadir personaje"))
        self.Btn5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Listar Personajes"))
        self.menuArchivo.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Archivo"))
        self.menuEditar.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Editar"))
        self.menuHerramientas.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Herramientas"))
        self.menuAyuda.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Ayuda"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

run.py -->Ejecuta la ventana principal

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from rnd_char_ui import Ui_Rndchr
from model import *

class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.model =Model()

        self.Btn1.clicked.connect(self.abrir_rndchr)

    def abrir_rndchr(self):
        self.window =QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui =Ui_Rndchr()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        #MainWindow.hide()
        self.window.show()



if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window=Principal()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

rnd_char_ui.py

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Rndchr(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialogo")
        Dialog.resize(470, 324)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 30, 271, 81))
        self.label2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label2.setObjectName("label2")
        self.Btn6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.Btn6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 161, 151))
        self.Btn6.setObjectName("Btn6")
        self.Btn7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.Btn7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 130, 161, 151))
        self.Btn7.setObjectName("Btn7")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Personaje Aleatorio"))
        self.label2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">TextLabel</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.Btn6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Obtener personaje"))
        self.Btn7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Salir"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

model.py -->Ejecuta la ventana secundaria.

```
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from rnd_char_ui import Ui_Rndchr
from main_ui import *
import os
import random

class Model (QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Rndchr):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Btn6.clicked.connect(self.resultado)

        self.Btn7.clicked.connect(self.salir)


    @pyqtSlot()     
    def resultado():
        lista1=["Gen","Gen2","Gen3","Gen8"]
        opc1 =random.choice(lista1)
        if opc1 == "Gen":
            model.Genm()
        elif opc1 == "Gen2":
            model.Gen2m()
        elif opc1 == "Gen3":
            model.Gen3m()
        elif opc1 == "Gen8":
            model.Gen8m()

    def Genm():
        gen = open('listas/gen.txt')
        lgen=gen.readlines()
        gen.close()
        model=lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)]
        while model =="\n":
            model=lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)-1]
        self.label2.setText(model)

    def Gen2m():
        gen= open('listas/gen2.txt')
        lgen=gen.readlines()
        gen.close()
        model=lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)]
        while model == "\n":
            model=lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)-1]
        self.label2.setText(model)

    def Gen3m():
        gen = open('listas/gen3.txt')
        lgen=gen.readlines()
        gen.close()
        model = lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)]
        while model == "\n":
            model=lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)-1]
        self.label2.setText(model)

    def Gen8m():
        gen = open('listas/gen3.txt')
        lgen=gen.readlines()
        gen.close()
        model=lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)]
        while model =="\n":
            model=lgen[random.randint(0, len(lgen)-1)-1]
        self.label2.setText(model)

    def salir():
        exit()




if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window =Model()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Gracias de antemano y disculpar si hay algún error al postear. 
    Es mi primer post.

Answer (score 0):

```
class login(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(login, self).__init__()
        loadUi('login.ui', self)

        rutaDeImagen = "C:/Users/AlvaroBC/Desktop/Ciclo 2019 - I/Disenno de Software/PROYECTO DE ESTE CICLO/ProyectoDsw/silueta.png"
        self.loginTLfoto.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(rutaDeImagen))

        self.loginTFusuario.setPlaceholderText("Ingrese Usuario")
        self.loginTFcontra.setPlaceholderText("Ingrese Contraseña")

        # para validar q solo sea unos caracrteres
        # self.loginTFusuario.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9]+||[a-z]+")))
        # self.loginTFcontra.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9]+")))

        self.loginTFcontra.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.loginJBIngresar.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self, e):
        print("Contraseña: ", self.loginTFcontra.text())
        if((self.loginTFusuario.text() == "" and self.loginTFcontra.text() == "") or (self.loginTFusuario.text() == "" and self.loginTFcontra.text() != "") or (self.loginTFusuario.text() != "" and self.loginTFcontra.text() == "")):
            # dif tipos de MSSBox -> http://www.pythondiario.com/2014/12/dialogos-en-pyqt-con-qmessagebox-python.html
            QMessageBox.information(
                self, "ERROR", "Complete ambos campos, o Ingrese correctamente sus datos", QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.cambiosEnLoginUsuario()
        else:
            if(self.loginTFusuario.text() == "admin" and self.loginTFcontra.text() == "admin"):

                QMessageBox.information(
                    self, "Correcto", "Bienvenido Administrador", QMessageBox.Ok)

                self.cambioEnLoginAdmin()
                self.abrirVentanaAdmin()

            else:
                QMessageBox.information(
                    self, "Correcto", "Bienvenido Usuario", QMessageBox.Ok)
                self.cambiosEnLoginUsuario()
                self.abrirVentanaUsuario()

    def cambiosEnLoginUsuario(self):
        self.loginTFusuario.setText("")
        self.loginTFcontra.setText("")

    def cambioEnLoginAdmin(self):
        self.cambiosEnLoginUsuario()

    def abrirVentanaAdmin(self):
        print("entre abrirVentanaAdmin")
        self.hide()
        otraventanaA = ventanaAdmin(self)
        otraventanaA.show()

    def abrirVentanaUsuario(self):
        print("entre abrirVentanaUsuario")
        self.hide()
        otraventanaU = ventanaUsuario(self)
        otraventanaU.show()



class ventanaAdmin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ventanaAdmin, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('ventanaAdmin.ui', self)

        self.vAJBregresarINICIO.clicked.connect(self.abrirLogin)
        self.vAJBCAPTURAR.clicked.connect(self.abrirVentanaRegistrar)

    def abrirLogin(self):
        self.parent().show()
        self.close()

    def abrirVentanaRegistrar(self):
        print("entre ventanaRegistrar")
        self.hide()
        otraventanaA = ventanaRegistrar(self)
        otraventanaA.show()
```

Comment: recien veo tu publicacion, espero que te sirva este parte de mi codigo, ademas esto es para llamar al main, no se porque no me dejaba subirlo, tambien soy nuevo aca, te aclaro que yo lo que hice fue crear un .ui por el qt design y solo importaba en python, en youtube hay varios videos de esos

Comment: app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = login()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Answer (score 0):

class ventanaAdmin(QMainWindow):

```
// esta clase no importa , al igual q la funcion, solo lo hice
// porque no me deja poner lineas sin que este dentro de una clase o funcion
// de app para abajo es lo q importa, y esto esta en ninguna clase,                                   introducir el código aquí//  es como si fuese el  introducir el código aquí`main
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = login()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```